# How to generate plots by comparing data read from two different text files in python?

Tags: python, plot

I have two text files. The first one is of the form:

```
K_1, 1
K_2, 2
J_1, 3
J_2, 4
J_3, 5
L_1, 6
```

The second file has the form:

```
K_2, 6
K_1, 5
J_2, 4
J_3, 4
J_1, 5
L_1, 4
```

where the first column in both files contains the same set of strings but the second column is different with values range from 1 to 6 (min value is 1 an max value is 6).

I need to get two plots from these files...

The first plot takes each of these text files as input and creates a graph with 1,2,3,4,5,6 numbers on the x-axis and the respective counts of 1s, 2s, 3s etc on the y-axis. So, I would like to make a comparison of the second column values of each file in one plot.

In the second plot, I need the difference between column values. That is for K_1, the value from the first file is 1 and the value from the second file is 5. I need to calculate the absolute difference between those and return value 4 (abs(1-5)=4). The difference is calculated for two values of the same string (here it is K_1). Finally, I need to record "values with no difference", values with 1-difference, values with 2-difference, values with 3-difference, values with 4-difference, and values with 5-difference on the x-axis and their respective counts on the y-axis.

Can anybody please help me to plot this with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections

file_txt1 = open('your_file1_path_and_name.txt', 'r')
lines1 = [line.split(', ') for line in file_txt1.readlines()]
column1 = [line[0] for line in lines1]
values1 = [int(line[1]) for line in lines1]
nb_lines = len(column1)


file_txt2 = open('your_file2_path_and_name.txt', 'r')
lines2 = [line.split(', ') for line in file_txt2.readlines()]
column2 = [line[0] for line in lines2]
values2 = [int(line[1]) for line in lines2]


# Check if the lines names are the same for both files
if collections.Counter(column1) != collections.Counter(column2) :
  raise ValueError("files '{}' and '{}' don't have the same lines names".format(file_txt1.name, file_txt2.name))


# First plot
x = list(range(1,7))
y1 = [values1.count(i) for i in x]
y2 = [values2.count(i) for i in x]
plt.plot(x,y1, label = "file '{}'".format(file_txt1.name))
plt.plot(x,y2, label = "file '{}'".format(file_txt2.name))
plt.legend()
plt.title('Counts of numbers in each file')
plt.show()

# Second plot
values2_in_order = [values2[column2.index(line_name)] for line_name in column1] # Gives a list with the same elements as values2, but this time in the same order as values1
y3 = [abs(values1[i] - values2_in_order[i]) for i in range(nb_lines)]
plt.plot(column1, y3)
plt.title('Absolute differences of lines between both files')
plt.show()

# Third plot
y4 = [y3.count(i) for i in range(6)]
plt.plot(list(range(6)), y4)
plt.title('Counts of absolute differences')
plt.show()
```

Comment: before calculating the absolute difference, we need to check if values1 and values2 correspond to the same string..how to check that?

Comment: @Simran I have edited my answer, I haven't seen at first that the lines names of the two files could be different, sorry for that. Now it should work just fine, let me know if I've done something wrong